# Looping through a particular column to obtain sub dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data frames and want to create sub data frames, based on the value in the 'counter' column, what would be the best approcah?

```
    Zeit    RPM  Counter
0   1     1000   1
1   2     1000   1
2   3     1100   2
3   4     1200   2
4   5     1300   3
5   6     1400   3
6   7     1500   4
7   8     1600   4
8   9     1700   5
9   10    1800   5
10  11    1900   6
```

Basically, an elegant way to write a loop, instead of cherry-picking this way:

```
df_1=df[df['counter']==1]
df_2=df[df['counter']==2]
df_3=df[df['counter']==3]
df_4=df[df['counter']==4]
df_5=df[df['counter']==5]
df_6=df[df['counter']==6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables:

```
dfs = {k: df[df['counter'] == k] for k in df['counter'].unique()}
```

Then access your slices by dictionary key. For example, to access a slice where counter = 3, use `dfs[3]`.

If you need only a subset of slices, replace `df['counter'].unique()` with this subset, e.g. `range(1, 7)` for 1-6. If you need *all* slices, you can simplify the logic:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('counter')))
```